# Win10 No Boot. Freezes on load screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, freeze

So my computer gets into a state where it continually locks up at the Windows 10 Logo on boot. The last driver that is shown in the logs to load is "usbvideo.sys" so I'm assuming it fails to load on the next driver which should be "WinUSB.SYS". When I put Win7 on the computer everything boots fine, but right when I go back to Win10 the same thing happens.

After repeated boot attempts, it will occasionally pass the Windows logo and try to start Windows, but then get a BSOD pointing to a "DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION". Any help or suggestions to figue out the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this problem arises when a device in or connected to the computer does not respond.
The reason is most probably a malfunctioning hardware component or a bad
driver update.

I suggest disconnecting every single device that is non-essential for the boot
and see if the boot proceeds. If it does, add devices one by one until you find
the problematic one.

For further analyzing the problem, you will need to post the minidump file
of the crash, found in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`.
If you cannot boot from the disk, you will need to boot from a boot USB
of Windows or Linux.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. So I have all unused USB devices disconnected and still get the error. However, when I check for the minidump it's not there, nothing was created. When I try and boot from a USB I also get the same error when loading Win10

Comment: Do you manage to boot Windows at all?

Comment: I can boot Win7. Win10 will not boot at all. I'm doing some more in depth troubleshooting today and will update with everything I find.